# executeUpdate doesnt commit sqlServe

Tags: java, sql-server

So this is my code

```
try{
  PreparedStatement stmnt=conn.prepareStatement("update tblEmployee set Name=? where id=?");
  stmnt.setString(1, "john");
  stmnt.setString(2, "123");
  int i=stmnt.executeUpdate();
  conn.commit();
  System.out.println(i);
} catch...
```

No exception is thrown, the value of *i* is 1 but the transaction is not committed. I tried to set autocommit to false and commit transaction manually but still doesn't work. what can possibly causes this?
And yes, I can execute the statement in sql server management studio.

Comment: So what name does your tblEmployee table show at id 123?

Comment: it shows Alex but if i execute the statement in management studio the name is changed to john

Comment: that is odd. is your id a String for sure? try `setInt()` instead.

Comment: yes it should be a String, id and Name are both nchar(10)

Comment: As a sanity check, make sure the java app and SSMS are using the same database.  Use SQL Server Profiler to trace the statements.  Perhaps there is inadvertent transaction nesting.